# Sql ONLY keyword

Tags: sql

In SQL grammar I found strange rule that suggest that `select * from ONLY (t1)` is valid SQL.

My question is: what does `ONLY` mean in this context?

It is in "7.6 table reference" section of spec:

```
<table primary> ::=
           <table or query name> [ [ AS ] <correlation name> [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ] ]
     |     <derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name> [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
     |     <lateral derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name> [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
     |     <collection derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name> [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
     |     <table function derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name> [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
     |     <only spec> [ [ AS ] <correlation name> [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ] ]
     |     <left paren> <joined table> <right paren> 

<only spec> ::= ONLY <left paren> <table or query name> <right paren>
```

Comment: What DB engine?

Comment: @juergend This is part of SQL Standard - Optional features: `2.1.2.145 S111, ONLY in query expressions`

Comment: @juergend I'm have no specific engine. It is in SQL 2003 spec. I try to create generic sql parser.

Comment: The standard says: *The <table reference> references the table that consists of every row of T. If ONLY is specified, then the <table reference> references the table that consists of every
row in T, except those rows that have a subrow in a proper subtable of T.* **But I never came across that keyword being used anywhere.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ONLY keyword is used to restrict the tables used in a query if the table(s) participate in table inheritance.

Further down in the specs it is explained as:

> If ONLY is specified, then the result of TP is a table that consists of every row in T, except those rows that have a subrow in a proper subtable of T

To my knowledge this is currently only supported by [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

The effect can be seen with the following example:

```
create table base (id integer, some_data varchar(100));
create table child () inherits (base);

insert into base values (1, 'base');
insert into child values (2, 'child');
```

The following:

```
select *
from base;
```

returns:

```
id | some_data
---+----------
 1 | base     
 2 | child
```

Whereas the following:

```
select *
from only (base);
```

returns:

```
id | some_data
---+----------
 1 | base
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/JVUM87016

Comment: World is full of wonders. Use SQL for 10 years and only today I learn that it support inheritance.

Comment: @talex: if you had used Postgres you would already have known ;)